# How can I get the value of ArrayOfObjects of MongoDb with Java syntax

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

My MongoDb Document Looks like below , I need to get the value of ArrayOfObjects of Mongodb with java syntax.I am facing an issue to get the value of Email Systems.Bob and Email Systems.Wild . Can anyone suggest me how to get the value of ArrayOfObjects in Mongodb please

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0890e870e631865877e"), 
    "user" : "testuser", 
    "Email" : "testuser@sample.com", 
    "Batch Systems" : [
        "STAR", 
        "STORY", 
        "ITEMS",    
    ], 
    "Email Systems" : [
        {
            "Bob" : {
                "System" : "Bob", 
                **"result"** : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "Wild" : {
                "System" : "Wild", 
                "result" : true
            }
        },
        {
            "CRaft" : {
                "System" : "Craft", 
                "result" : false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Code Syntax:

```
MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = this.mongoClient.getDatabase(database);
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoDatabase.getCollection(collection);
        Document emailQuery = new Document();

        AggregateIterable<Document> output = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
                new Document("$unwind", "$Email Systems"),
                new Document("$match", new Document("Email Systems", Atlas
        ));

        for (Document doc : output) {

        }
        return system;
    }
```

Comment: Kindly show the code you are using to fetch the values

Comment: Thanks for your Reply .I have updated the code in summary .Please help to get the values of Email Systems.Bob and Email Systems.Wild

Comment: @HeenaTabassum, I have added the code in summary .Can you help me with the syntax